# how to delete table row in table layout in android

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

```
void init()
{
   intcolumnwidth1 = int_scr_wd*55;
   intcolumnwidth1 = intcolumnwidth1/100;
   for (int i = 0; i < strarr.length-1; i++)
   {
      strinarr = fun1.split(strarr[i].trim(),"^");
      tr1 = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
      txt1=new TextView(this);
      txt1.setWidth(intcolumnwidth1);
      txt1.setText(strinarr[0]);
      tr1.addView(txt1);
      tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams));
   }
}
```

Scenario is this when for the first i open this page it dynamically adds rows in the table layout ... but if after some time data in database changes ... when i click on refresh button it appends the new data after the old data in the table layout... all i need is the solution for how to refresh or delete textview that already exists in the table layout...

thanx..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29)

```
row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);
table.removeView(row);
```

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that the rows will have static ids if they are added dynamically.

Answer (score 18):

This method I have written removes all rows except the first one. It is useful if you don't want to remove the header row, for example:

```
private void cleanTable(TableLayout table) {

    int childCount = table.getChildCount();

    // Remove all rows except the first one
    if (childCount > 1) {
        table.removeViews(1, childCount - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is a old thread but I as shocked when I came across this without a decent answer.

I do it like this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);       
table.removeAllViews();
```

That will remove all of the child views, in this case rows and everything.  It doesn't seem by your description that you want to delete just one row, but that you want to remove them and then load the rows again.  The above code will do the removing part.

Answer (score 6):

The other solutions require your rows to have unique ids.

If they don't have unique ids then how about using:

```
tl.removeView(rowIndex);
```

In any case, you should try learning how to use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) or [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) because they are specifically designed for displaying the content of a database query in a list. See [Binding to Data with AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the textview to be deleted. The TextView can be identified by setting a unique id using setId() or using a unique tag using setTag().

It can then be identified by TextView tv = (TextView) tr1.findViewByTag(**unique tag**);

Use removeView to delete the View.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
tl.removeView(tl.getChildAt(index));
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

look this code to remove row in table

```
private List<View> listViewRow;

if (listViewRow.size() > 0) {
    for (View view : listViewRow) {
        table.removeView(view);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    row.addView((new TextView(context).setText("Teste")), 0);
    row.addView((new TextView(context).setText("Teste")), 1);
    row.addView((new TextView(context).setText("Teste")), 2);

    listViewRow.add(row);
    table.addView(row, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         TableRow row = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(i);
         table.removeView(row);
      }
 }, 100);
```

Where i - is row position, wich you want to delete.